# How can I set the fiscal year in my Oracle Select Statement

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to convert a T_SQL query into an oracle query to get information for a fiscal year; which for me runs from Oct 1 thru Sept 30  This is what I am trying to use but am getting an error message "invalid SQL Statement at line 1

```
var FromDate date
IF extract(month from sysdate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12
exec :FromDate := (extract(month from sysdate), 10, 1) ELSE
exec :FromDate := (extract(year from sysdate)) - 1, 10, 1)
                         SELECT        COUNT(DISTINCT [CSMAST].[CM_CALL])
                          FROM            [TIBURON].[CSMAST] [CSMAST] JOIN
                                                   [TIBURON].[SSCTAB] [SSCTAB] ON ([CSMAST].[CM_DID_1] = [SSCTAB].[RC_KEY])
                          WHERE        [CSMAST].[CM_DATE] >= @FromDate AND [SSCTAB].[RC_TYPE] = 'O*
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your 'IF' at line 2 is out of place - it isn't SQL, and isn't in a PL/SQL context. Your error is coming from your client. All the square brackets are wrong too, as is the @ syntax. You might need to step back and think about how Oracle works. And then at least show your table definitions, sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

`IF` isn't a SQL construct and you're using it outside a PL/SQL block, so the client you're using is correctly telling you it doesn't recognise it. You probably don't want to resort to PL/SQL though, as you can do it without generating the start date as a bind variable as a separate step.

If I understand what you're trying to do you can use a case expression in your query to decide the date range, something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CSMAST.CM_CALL)
FROM TIBURON.CSMAST
JOIN TIBURON.SSCTAB ON CSMAST.CM_DID_1 = SSCTAB.RC_KEY
WHERE CSMAST.CM_DATE >=
  CASE WHEN extract(month from sysdate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN
    -- get start of current year, add 9 months to get this October
    ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 9)
  ELSE
    -- get start of current year, subtract 3 months to get previous October
    ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'YYYY'), -3)
  END
AND SSCTAB.RC_TYPE = 'O*'
```

Not sure if that last line is supposed to be a wildcard; if so it would be:

```
AND SSCTAB.RC_TYPE LIKE 'O%'
```

You can see the dates that case expression produces with a dummy query:

```
WITH t (dt) AS (
  SELECT add_months(SYSDATE, 6-LEVEL) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 27
)
SELECT dt,
  CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN
    -- get start of current year, add 9 months to get this October
    ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(dt, 'YYYY'), 9)
  ELSE
    -- get start of current year, subtract 3 months to get previous October
    ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(dt, 'YYYY'), -3)
  END AS calculated
FROM t
ORDER BY dt;

DT         CALCULATED
---------- ----------
2014-10-27 2014-10-01
2014-11-27 2014-10-01
2014-12-27 2014-10-01
2015-01-27 2014-10-01
2015-02-27 2014-10-01
2015-03-27 2014-10-01
2015-04-27 2014-10-01
2015-05-27 2014-10-01
2015-06-27 2014-10-01
2015-07-27 2014-10-01
2015-08-27 2014-10-01
2015-09-27 2014-10-01
2015-10-27 2015-10-01
2015-11-27 2015-10-01
2015-12-27 2015-10-01
2016-01-27 2015-10-01
2016-02-27 2015-10-01
2016-03-27 2015-10-01
2016-04-27 2015-10-01
2016-05-27 2015-10-01
2016-06-27 2015-10-01
2016-07-27 2015-10-01
2016-08-27 2015-10-01
2016-09-27 2015-10-01
2016-10-27 2016-10-01
2016-11-27 2016-10-01
2016-12-27 2016-10-01
```

You could even simplify that so you only truncate the date once, and have a single `ADD_MONTHS()` call, and put the case expression *inside* that as it's the number you add or subtract is the only part that changes:

```
WHERE CSMAST.CM_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'YYYY'),
  CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 9 ELSE -3 END)
AND SSCTAB.RC_TYPE LIKE 'O%'
```

which has the same effect.

Quick demo to show earlier dates are ignored, using mocked-up data for your two tables:

```
with CSMAST(cm_date, cm_call, cm_did_1) as (
  select date '1999-12-31', 1, 1 from dual
  union all select date '2014-09-30', 1, 2 from dual
  union all select date '2015-10-01', 1, 3 from dual
  union all select date '2015-12-31', 2, 4 from dual
  union all select date '2016-01-01', 2, 5 from dual
  union all select date '2016-09-30', 2, 6 from dual
  union all select date '2016-10-01', 3, 7 from dual
  union all select date '2016-12-31', 3, 8 from dual
),
SSCTAB (rc_key, rc_type) as (
  select level, 'O*' from dual connect by level < 10
)
SELECT * -- COUNT(DISTINCT CSMAST.CM_CALL)
FROM CSMAST
JOIN SSCTAB ON CSMAST.CM_DID_1 = SSCTAB.RC_KEY
WHERE CSMAST.CM_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'YYYY'),
  CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sysdate) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 THEN 9 ELSE -3 END)
AND SSCTAB.RC_TYPE LIKE 'O%';

CM_DATE        CM_CALL   CM_DID_1     RC_KEY RC
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --
 2015-10-01          1          3          3 O*
 2015-12-31          2          4          4 O*
 2016-01-01          2          5          5 O*
 2016-09-30          2          6          6 O*
 2016-10-01          3          7          7 O*
 2016-12-31          3          8          8 O*

 6 rows selected
```

Comment: Sorry for no response got pulled off onto another project.  I tried your suggestion but had 2 issues first the query took a LONG time to run.  When it finished I had records starting with the year 1999?

Comment: I've done some testing and it seems to work OK; with mocked-up data of course, but I've included some from 1999 and it's ignoring everything before 2015-10-01. Are you sure those rows are 1999, not 2099, say? Is CM_DATE indexed, and actually a date? And just to rule out a few oddities, is CSMAST a table or a view?